# Have I upgraded my cabal-install?

Tags: macos, haskell, cabal

I just installed Haskell from [it's official site](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/). After that, following it's quick-start tutorial.

I run:

```
cabal update
```

Which shows this message:

```
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Note: there is a new version of cabal-install available.
To upgrade, run: cabal install cabal-install
```

I run:

```
cabal install cabal-install
```

and check if the update was successful with

```
cabal update
```

The result, it shows me the same message from the start:

```
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Note: there is a new version of cabal-install available.
To upgrade, run: cabal install cabal-install
```

**So, did I upgrade the cabal-install or not? How do I check my cabal's version?**

*Important: I'm using the 64 bits version for Mac OS X.*

Comment: Use `which cabal` to find out which install of cabal you're using, cabal probably isn't installing the newly downloaded version to your PATH. Check ~/bin for another cabal executable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had a similar issue after installing the Haskell platform `2012.4.0.0` on OSX. When I ran `cabal install cabal-install`, it ended with:

```
cabal: ../ghc-7.4.2/lib/cabal-install-1.16.0.2/bin/cabal: does not exist
```

So I guessed it got its paths mixed up somewhere. However the executable was actually built successfully (check for `~/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.4.2/lib/cabal-install-1.16.0.2/bin/cabal`) and I just copied it from there to `~/Library/Haskell/bin` which is on my path.

Thereafter everything ran OK:

```
$ which cabal
/Users/luke/Library/Haskell/bin/cabal
$ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0.3 of the Cabal library
```

Comment: A similar situation occurred on my Windows system. The per-user cabal install directory will be in `%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin`, so this needs to be appended to the path as a higher priority.

Answer (score 29):

In my case (and probably others?) cabal is initially installed in `/usr/local/bin` by homebrew when installing `haskell-platform`. When upgrading cabal, the version is installed to `$HOME/.cabal/bin/cabal`. You ought to place your cabal bins higher in your `$PATH`, like so:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: This didn't work for me on homebrew+mavericks. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19736802/388010) answer did, though.

Comment: @Sebastian - Right - IF you're using the package directly from http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/. Homebrew uses `$HOME/.cabal` and `/usr/local/bin`, as opposed to `/Library/Haskell/bin`. I realize now that the solution above answers a slightly different question than the one the OP asked.

Comment: This was the issue for me.

Comment: So... Did the original installation just become obsolete then?

Answer (score 12):

Everyone seems to experience a slightly different issue here. In my case, `cabal` was built successfully and installed to `~/Library/Haskell/bin`.

As noted in `~/.cabal/config`, adding `~/Library/Haskell/bin` to `PATH` solved the issue.

Below is the description in `~/.cabal/config`:

```
-- === Built executables will be installed in:
--     ~/Library/Haskell/bin
--
-- You may wish to place this on your PATH by adding the following
-- line to your ~/.bash_profile:
--     export PATH="$HOME/Library/Haskell/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: This is way to go, IMO.

Answer (score 10):

On OS X 10.8 I had to add `/Library/Haskell/bin` to my PATH (put it before `/usr/bin`). Adding that fixed the error message

Comment: This is right.The old version in `/usr/bin` shadowed the version in `/Library/Haskell/bin`. Quite a messy installation I'd say... Why don't they just replace the old version in `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 3):

`cabal --version` gives you the version of cabal you're running. If you want to see the version of cabal-install you have, run `cabal info cabal-install` and look at the *versions installed* line.

For me on OS X, *versions installed* is `[unknown]`, after running `cabal install cabal-install`, which is not great.

Comment: Maybe because it's uknown it always tells you tu upgrade?

Comment: @LuisOrtegaAraneda No, the cabal binary knows its version, it only tells you to upgrade if there is a newer one on hackage. Probably, the new one was installed in a directory not in your path. Which OS? On Linux (and OS X, iirc), you should add `$HOME/.cabal/bin` to your path; on Windows, something like `Users\You\AppData\Roaming`.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work with that path, in OS X you have to use `/Library/Haskell/`. And, when I do cabal info cabal-install it says `[unknown]`

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too.

After running `which cabal`, I found that it was using `/usr/bin/cabal`. Deleting this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that cabal by default installs packages locally for the current user and therefore will not be part of the PATH. Look at the 
[Cabal documentation](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal-Install) specifically step 1.2.1 where you can change the configuration to install things globally by default (not recommended).

The way I installed cabal was `cabal --global install cabal-install` but still had problems with the path which since the default installation of Haskell puts the path in this order `C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin;C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\bin;` where the first path has precedence over the second one. With the --global flag cabal installed the binary to `C:\Program Files\Haskell\bin` which isn't in my path but must be added before the `C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin` path.

Taken from the documentation

> You must put the cabal.exe in a directory that is on your %PATH%, for example C:\Program Files\Haskell\bin.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, a combination of several answers here was required to get through this issue.  I'll attempt to provide a more comprehensive solution in one answer for anyone else in my situation.

- For starters, running `which cabal` showed me that `/usr/bin/cabal` was being loaded, which was a symlink to `/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.8.3-x86_64/bin/cabal`.  I believe newer versions of cabal were being installed, but this path was specific to a single version so they were ignored.  Adding `/Library/Haskell/bin` to the front of my `$PATH` remedied that situation.
- Second, and more importantly, the new versions of `cabal-install` were being installed into my cabal sandbox instead of the system location.  I didn't see any other answers suggesting this, but after a little monkeying around I found that moving outside of my application's directory allowed cabal to actually install to the system.
- Finally, adding the `--global` flag to the command fixed the problem.  My final command was `cabal install --global cabal-install`.  After this, I was finally able to update properly.

TL;DR: if you use cabal sandboxes, move outside the directory of your project and run `cabal install --global cabal-install`.  Also, check your `$PATH` variable as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the new version of cabal was being installed in the .cabal-sandbox of the project I was in.

e.g. Checking the version:

```
./.cabal-sandbox/bin/cabal --version
```

So I needed to upgrade it outside of that.  This was on OSX.