# "cabal install cabal-install" doesn't update cabal version in OSX

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm a newbie to haskell and cabal, so I'm probably missing something simple.

I updated cabal-install:

```
sudo cabal install cabal-install
Password:
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring cabal-install-1.22.0.0...
Building cabal-install-1.22.0.0...
Installed cabal-install-1.22.0.0
Updating documentation index
```

However `cabal --version` says:

```
cabal-install version 1.18.0.5
using version 1.18.1.4 of the Cabal library
```

What happened to cabal-install 1.22.0.0?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two ways of making `cabal` install packages globally. Note that, as a result, `cabal` may require sudo.

This command will install `<PACKAGE>` globally:

```
$ cabal install <PACKAGE> --global
```

As a more general solution, edit the file `~/.cabal/config` and set `user-install` to `False`. This will automatically set the `--global` flag so you can just write `cabal install <PACKAGE>` without any worry. Here's a snippet of my `config` file:

```
...
-- split-objs: False
-- executable-stripping: True
user-install: False
-- package-db:
-- flags:
...
```

You may also want to set `root-cmd` to `sudo` if it's not already, so that `cabal` will automatically prompt for the root password when it encounters a permission problem.

There's some more info online [here](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal-Install#The_cabal-install_configuration_file).

Answer (score 5):

I see that there's an updated cabal at `~/Library/Haskell/bin`, so I could replace /usr/bin/cabal with a symbolic link to this copy or I could copy this binary to `/usr/bin`.

I'm still interested if there is a more elegant/canonical way to make sure the new cabal is what gets used by default.

Comment: It's all determined by your PATH.

Comment: Have a look at these answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21200691/3649209,
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19736802/3649209.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: Try running `hash -r`

Bash has a PATH hashtable that maps commands to the location of binaries. You may still have an old version of cabal installed somewhere in your PATH (possibly in a sandbox). Since cabal is not a new command, the hashtable will keep serving up the old version. `hash -r` rebuilds the hashtable, so the shell will correctly find the new version (providing it appears earlier in your path than the old one).

Comment: Small nit: `hash -r` *clears* the hash table.  It is then rebuilt on a per-command basis each subsequent time an unqualified path is invoked as a command.